# NullPointerException in Saxon while parsing XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using Saxon PE 9.4 version. I am frequently getting an issue while parsing XSL but the issue is not consistent. Sometime it comes and sometime it doesn't come. Following is the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Bindery.getGlobalVariableValue(Bindery.java:264)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.GlobalParam.evaluateVariable(GlobalParam.java:47)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.VariableReference.evaluateVariable(VariableReference.java:488)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.VariableReference.iterate(VariableReference.java:441)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.Atomizer.iterate(Atomizer.java:230)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.AtomicSequenceConverter.iterate(AtomicSequenceConverter.java:281)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.CardinalityChecker.evaluateItem(CardinalityChecker.java:249)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.ItemChecker.evaluateItem(ItemChecker.java:178)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.evaluate(ExpressionTool.java:320)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.lazyEvaluate(ExpressionTool.java:434)
   at com.saxonica.expr.JavaExtensionFunctionCall.iterate(JavaExtensionFunctionCall.java:275)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.evaluateItem(Expression.java:411)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.AtomicSequenceConverter.evaluateItem(AtomicSequenceConverter.java:325)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf.evaluateItem(ValueOf.java:273)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.SimpleNodeConstructor.iterate(SimpleNodeConstructor.java:258)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.DocumentInstr.evaluateItem(DocumentInstr.java:302)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.Atomizer.evaluateItem(Atomizer.java:240)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.CastExpression.evaluateItem(CastExpression.java:320)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.ValueComparison.effectiveBooleanValue(ValueComparison.java:682)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:789)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:212)
   at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1034)
   at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1959)
   at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1805)
   at dyngrammar.transform.TransformXSL.parseXSLT(TransformXSL.java:320)
```

XSLT Used :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:request="java:common.RequestSearchCommand" exclude-result-prefixes="request">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="decodeFlag"/>
    <xsl:param name="requestString"/>
    <xsl:variable name="segmentName">ABC</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="searchBlbContent">(CU0 ##)|(AMIS ##)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="matchFlag">
            <xsl:value-of select="request:searchPattren($requestString, $segmentName, $searchBlbContent, $decodeFlag)" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$matchFlag = 'true'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <ABC></ABC>
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please suggest how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like your XSLT is using an invalid variable reference. Can you show us the XSLT that is producing the problem?

Comment: @JLRishe XSLT is not an issue because when I re run for same XSLT it runs fine.

Comment: Even if it runs fine sometimes, there is a very high likelihood that the error is related to your particular XSLT. So please share it.

Comment: @JLRishe I have updated the question with XSLT.

Comment: Is that your exact code? `searchPattren`? And this sometimes works?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes this is the exact code. I am using a licensed version and search pattern is my Java method which I am calling from XSLT

Comment: Is there any multi-threading involved? In particular, are you perhaps using the JAXP Transformer object in more than one thread concurrently?

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes multi-threading is involved.

Comment: Then we need to see the details of the multithreading. Note that concurrent use of a JAXP Transformer is not allowed: if you want to run the same stylesheet in more than one thread, create a single Templates object for the compiled stylesheet, and then one Transformer object for each transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, Saxon is encountering a `NullPointerException` when trying to get the value for one of the global parameters used in this expression:

```
request:searchPattren($requestString, $segmentName, $searchBlbContent, $decodeFlag)
```

This expression involves two global parameters: `$requestString`, and `$decodeFlag`.

Since you only encounter this error sometimes, this suggests that you are *sometimes* passing in a null value for one (or both) of these parameters.

Please verify that you are never passing in null values for either of these parameters.

Comment: For same XML it sometimes return the correct value and sometimes it returns this exception. Input XML & XSLT remains the same.

Comment: @NiteshGupta The XML is not the problem. The parameter values are the problem.

Comment: ah Sorry I didn't read the answer correctly. Yes parameters can never be null.

Comment: @NiteshGupta Can you show us the Java code where you are executing the XSLT?

Comment: I don't think that the error is caused by passing in null as the value of a parameter. I think it's a multi-threading issue. So yes, we need to see the Java application code.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, from the information given, I think it is very likely that the cause of this issue was that the JAXP Transformer object was being used to perform multiple transformations concurrently in different threads, which is not allowed.